# Excel Vlookup Changing location

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a project where I need mapping data (male=m female=f) when copying the information from one sheet to the current sheet. This is my code:

```
=VLOOKUP('Data'!L2,'Mapping Data'!B2:'Mapping Data'!C3,2,FALSE)
```

However, my issue is that when I copy and paste this to the cell bellow the !B2 and !C3 change to the next cell. I want those to stay at B2 and C3. I am new to excel formulas so I'm not sure how to get that to work or if that is even possible. Thank you ahead of time.

When it moves the B2 and C3 it shows

> "#N/A"

---

### | A            | B        | C

### |1|

### |2| Field Name | Code1    | Code2

### |3| Gender     | Female   | F

### |3|            | Male     | M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, $ is the anchor...

```
=VLOOKUP('Data'!L2,'Mapping Data'!$B$2:'Mapping Data'!$C$3,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Ok so the Anchors worked exactly how I wanted. The only issue now is that when it come to a "Male" it is not transforming it to M intsead it is the N/A

Comment: Case doesn't seem to matter, but spaces do; check for spaces, or trim them, in your data and lookup table.

Comment: I just added the lookup table to the question. Is that formatted correctly?

Comment: And the data and lookup have the same spacing

Comment: You have row 3 twice, if you have a blank and a header and Female is on 3 then Male is on 4, you'd want `'Mapping Data'!B$3:C$4`